# rspec/growl windows setup windows 7 64 bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, windows-7-x64, railstutorial.org, growl

I get the following error when I am trying to set this up. I can't figure out what's going on. I'm following Michael Hartl's Rail's tutorial trying to set up for first tests and nothing seems to be working.

```
C:\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec autotest
loading autotest/rspec2
C:/rails_projects/sample_app/.autotest:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- autotest/growl (LoadError)
    from C:/rails_projects/sample_app/.autotest:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.7.0/lib/autotest.rb:315:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.7.0/lib/autotest.rb:315:in `block in initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.7.0/lib/autotest.rb:314:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.7.0/lib/autotest.rb:314:in `initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/autotest/rspec2.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.7.0/lib/autotest.rb:244:in `new'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.7.0/lib/autotest.rb:244:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.7.0/bin/autotest:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/autotest:19:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/autotest:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Which version of the tutorial, Ruby, and Rails are you using?  Did you do a `bundle install` after changing the Gemfile to include autotest?

Comment: Used the railsinstaller. I have Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.2 I am following the screencasts (got the videos on udemy) I believe it's rails 3.0. I did run a bundle install after changing the gem file. Below = gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'



gem 'sqlite3'



group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

 
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development do
 gem 'autotest'
 gem 'ZenTest'
 gem 'autotest-rails-pure'
 gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.8"
 gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :test do
 gem 'rspec'
end

Comment: There is a new version of the tutorial `http://ruby.railstutorial.org/` that uses Rails 3.2.  If you use the Gemfile from the previous version it may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you, probably have a configuration for use growl on your .autotest file.
I think you may need add on your Gemfile the following line:

```
  gem "autotest-growl"
```